# Drawing parallel lines in QGIS 2.18?

Tags: qgis, editing, map-drawing, parallel-lines

Is there a button in QGIS that will allow me to create parallel lines?  I do not mean by using a script, or distance from.

I usually use ArcMap, and in ArcMap you just begin editing, select parallel lines, and click on the line you want to parallel from.  There is also a perpendicular and right angle option. I use these a lot at work to create "perfect" lines around buildings.

Can you do this in QGIS, and if so how do you do it?

The question, "Creating parallel lines at particular distance from lines which are part of a shapefile," does not answer my question. I do not want to do distance from.  In fact I do not want to parallel form line features.  I want to parallel form polygon Features.

Say I am drawing a square with a polygon, I want to be able to make the first line of the square, then right angle from that line, and then right angle until I complete the square.  (Making a perfect square)

Now that I have made a square around a building, I need to draw the boundary of the site.

So I would start by paralleling off of the building lines.

I do this at work on ArcMap all day.  It creates beautiful maps for my clients.  I am trying to find out if I can do this on QGIS.

Again, this is editing polygons, not lines. In ArcMap this editing tool is a toolbar called ****Feature Construction****

Comment: Try with qcad plugin

Comment: Also there is the advanced digitizing tool bar

Comment: QGIS 2.18 has 3 plugins you should look at: CADDigitize, CADTools, and QAD. QGIS 3.0 and later has the Shape Digitizing Toolbar. These are the closest features in QGIS to what you asked for. You should try them to find out if they meet your needs.